# How to save a JPEG file from RGB buffer in the easiest way (VS2008 C++)?

Tags: c++, jpeg, rgb, libjpeg, libjpeg-turbo

I've seen many guides and there always seem to be something missing.

**If someone can post here a complete "idiot's" guide it will be great!**

In any case, I will provide here what I've tried to do so far:
I've tried to download **libjpeg** and got confused with all the configerations needed and makefiles.
I've downloaded **libjpeg-turbo**, and currently I'm linking (Successfully) to jpeg.lib and including "jpeglib.h".

I'm using this code that I found on the web (after doing some small modifications to it cause it won't compile), which gives me run-time error ("a buffer overrun has occured") when the block ends (when the last '}' is called)

```
void TestModel3D::write_JPEG_file(char * filename, int quality, int w, int h)
{
    /* This struct contains the JPEG compression parameters and pointers to
    * working space (which is allocated as needed by the JPEG library).
    * It is possible to have several such structures, representing multiple
    * compression/decompression processes, in existence at once.  We refer
    * to any one struct (and its associated working data) as a "JPEG object".
    */
    struct jpeg_compress_struct cinfo;
    /* This struct represents a JPEG error handler.  It is declared separately
    * because applications often want to supply a specialized error handler
    * (see the second half of this file for an example).  But here we just
    * take the easy way out and use the standard error handler, which will
    * print a message on stderr and call exit() if compression fails.
    * Note that this struct must live as long as the main JPEG parameter
    * struct, to avoid dangling-pointer problems.
    */
    struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;
    /* More stuff */
    FILE * outfile;     /* target file */
    JSAMPROW row_pointer[1];    /* pointer to JSAMPLE row[s] */
    int row_stride;     /* physical row width in image buffer */



    /* Step 1: allocate and initialize JPEG compression object */

    /* We have to set up the error handler first, in case the initialization
    * step fails.  (Unlikely, but it could happen if you are out of memory.)
    * This routine fills in the contents of struct jerr, and returns jerr's
    * address which we place into the link field in cinfo.
    */
    cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr);
    /* Now we can initialize the JPEG compression object. */
    jpeg_create_compress(&cinfo);

    /* Step 2: specify data destination (eg, a file) */
    /* Note: steps 2 and 3 can be done in either order. */

    /* Here we use the library-supplied code to send compressed data to a
    * stdio stream.  You can also write your own code to do something else.
    * VERY IMPORTANT: use "b" option to fopen() if you are on a machine that
    * requires it in order to write binary files.
    */
    if ((outfile = fopen(filename, "wb")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "can't open %s\n", filename);
        // exit(1);
    }
    jpeg_stdio_dest(&cinfo, outfile);

    /* Step 3: set parameters for compression */

    /* First we supply a description of the input image.
    * Four fields of the cinfo struct must be filled in:
    */
    cinfo.client_data = (void*)&outfile;  
    cinfo.image_width = w;  /* image width and height, in pixels */
    cinfo.image_height = h;
    cinfo.input_components = 3;     /* # of color components per pixel */
    cinfo.in_color_space = JCS_RGB;     /* colorspace of input image */
    /* Now use the library's routine to set default compression parameters.
    * (You must set at least cinfo.in_color_space before calling this,
    * since the defaults depend on the source color space.)
    */
    jpeg_set_defaults(&cinfo);
    /* Now you can set any non-default parameters you wish to.
    * Here we just illustrate the use of quality (quantization table) scaling:
    */
    jpeg_set_quality(&cinfo, quality, TRUE /* limit to baseline-JPEG values */);

    /* Step 4: Start compressor */

    /* TRUE ensures that we will write a complete interchange-JPEG file.
    * Pass TRUE unless you are very sure of what you're doing.
    */
    jpeg_start_compress(&cinfo, TRUE);

    /* Step 5: while (scan lines remain to be written) */
    /*           jpeg_write_scanlines(...); */

    /* Here we use the library's state variable cinfo.next_scanline as the
    * loop counter, so that we don't have to keep track ourselves.
    * To keep things simple, we pass one scanline per call; you can pass
    * more if you wish, though.
    */
    row_stride = w * 3; /* JSAMPLEs per row in image_buffer */


    const int BYTE_SIZE = (160 * 3);
    UInt8 lineBuffer[BYTE_SIZE];
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
    {
        int j = 0;
        for (int x=0; x < w; x++)
        {
            //printf("j: %d.\n", (x*3));
            float r,g,b;
            //if (CVFAILED(grabImage->GetPixel(x,y,r,g,b)))
            //{
                //printf("GetPixel Error!\n");
            //}
            //else
            //{
                lineBuffer[x * 3] = r;
                lineBuffer[x * 3 + 1] = g;
                lineBuffer[x * 3 + 2] = b;
            //}

        }

        row_pointer[0] = & lineBuffer[0];
        (void) jpeg_write_scanlines(&cinfo, row_pointer, 1);
    }

    /* Step 6: Finish compression */

    //jpeg_finish_compress(&cinfo);

    /* After finish_compress, we can close the output file. */
    fclose(outfile);

    /* Step 7: release JPEG compression object */

    /* This is an important step since it will release a good deal of memory. */
    jpeg_destroy_compress(&cinfo);

    /* And we're done! */

}
```

Comment: Did you try a debugger?

Comment: To fix that error? As I said this code is something I got from the "outside" and it didn't even compile at the begining.. (used some private functions).. So before I start digging in it I need to know if there isn't any easier way, or to get confirmation that its good.. Or any other full guideness :)

Comment: About authenticity, this code is written by libjpeg authors. And is quite simple to make it work.